# Is it allowed to change one's qualifying long-term-care insurance after opting out from the long-term care payroll tax in Washington?

Tags: united-states, taxes, health-insurance, payroll-taxes, washington

After opting out from the long-term care payroll tax in Washington by purchasing a qualifying long-term-care insurance, one has to keep a qualifying long-term-care insurance, other one may get in trouble if audited. Is it allowed to change one's qualifying long-term-care insurance after opting out from the long-term care payroll tax in Washington? By after, I mean anytime after, e.g. the day after, or 10 years after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following answer from the [long-term care exemption support team](https://wacaresfund.wa.gov/contact-us/).

> If you already have an approved exemption, it’s up to you to decide to maintain or cancel your private long-term care policy.
>
> As the law is written the Long-Term Care Exemptions are permanent and for life.

Full email:

> ---------- Forwarded message ---------
> From: **ESD GP Paid Family and Medical Leave** <paidleave@esd.wa.gov>
> Date: Thu, 16 Feb 2023 at 10:25
> Subject: RE: LTC Exemption
> To: Franck Dernoncourt <...@gmail.com>
>
> Dear Franck Dernoncourt :
>
> Thank you for contacting ESD Leave & Care Div​​ision regarding the WA Cares Fund.
>
> If you already have an approved exemption, it’s up to you to decide to maintain or cancel your private long-term care policy.
>
> As the law is written the Long-Term Care Exemptions are permanent and for life.
>
> Should you have any questions or need assistance, please reply to this message, or call us Monday through Friday between 8:30 a.m. and 4:30 p.m. at (833) 717-2273.
>
> Best regards,
> Julie D.
> Customer Care Team
> Paid Family and Medical Leave | WA Cares Fund
> [paidleave.wa.gov](https://www.paidleave.wa.gov/) | [wacaresfund.wa.gov](https://www.wacaresfund.wa.gov/) | 1-833-717-2273

But of course, the law may change and close this apparent loophole.

---

Old answer:

I have discussed with several insurance brokers in Washington state: the consensus is that one is allowed to change (but not cancel) one's qualifying long-term-care insurance after opting out from the long-term care payroll tax in Washington state.

However, I read on https://mynorthwest.com/3319983/long-term-care-private-insurance-advice/amp/ that it's ok to drop the insurance:

> The way the law is currently written, you have the ability to drop that product. That is why the long-term market in the state collapsed … Carriers stopped selling long-term care insurance in Washington state,” she said. “It became apparent that … it became a tax-avoidance tool.”